# VBA Access - Función DSuma no reconoce el doble criterio

Tags: vba, ms-access

**¡Hola chicos! Espero que todos estén bien.**

Tengo una tabla [BALANCE_MOV] (Balance de Movimientos de Inventario) con los siguiente campos:

*[ID]: producto (texto)

*[INGRESOS]: cantidad ingresada de cada producto (número)

*[ALM_ING]: almacenes de ingreso (texto)

Con los cuales quiero hacer una consulta para saber **LA CANTIDAD INGRESADA DE CADA ID, SEGÚN UN ALMACÉN EN PARTICULAR DE NOMBRE "NNPU"**. Para ello utilizo los siguientes campos:

*[PUNTO]: mantenedor de almacenes (texto, en otra tabla)

*[IDP]: productos en stock (texto, en otra consulta)

*[INGRESOS_X_ALMACEN]: campo de la suma...con el problema.

Para hacer lo anterior planeo utilizar la **función DSuma, similar al SUMAR.SI.CONJUNTO de excel por lo que entiendo**, La cual **funciona si la ejecuto sólo con un criterio**: ya sea para sumar la cantidad según un ID, o el almacén en cuestión. PERO **si los combino NO funciona**, y me calcula un total que no logro descrubrir la razón.

Esta es la sintaxis que utilizo; Access no me reconoce un error en ella, sólo no calcula bien ¿Tiene algo mal? Mil gracias de antemano chic@s.

```
INGRESOS_X_ALMACEN: DSuma("[INGRESOS]";"[BALANCE_MOV]";"[ID]='" & [IDP] & "'" Y "[ALM_ING]='NNPU'")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que no entiendo es el motivo por el cual funciona con un solo criterio

Tomando el ejemplo de Microsoft

```
curX = DSuma("[Freight]", "Orders", "[ShipCountryRegion] = 'UK' Y [ShippedDate] > #1-1-95#")
```

Vemos que el tercer parámetro de la función, el que realiza el filtro es un `string`. En tu caso, este `string` no está bien construido puesto que no está correctamente concatenado, fíjate que la `Y` queda descolgada

```
"[ID]='" & [IDP] & "'" Y "[ALM_ING]='NNPU'")
```

Por otra parte el operador `Y` debería ser `AND` y debería quedar así:

```
INGRESOS_X_ALMACEN: DSuma("[INGRESOS]";"[BALANCE_MOV]";"[ID]='" & [IDP] & "' AND [ALM_ING]='NNPU'")
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por echarme una mano Roger. Seguí tu instrucción y corregí el código, mas, ahora me lanza un error de sintaxis "in query expression . (Error 3075)" ¿Qué piensas puede significar? ¿Algún error propio de mis tablas? Las estoy revisando otra vez ahora

Comment: No he utilizado nunca Access en Español, pero ¿es posible que en vez de poner `Y` y poninendo `AND` se solucione?

Comment: Siendo más específico, el error arrojado es este: "Error de sintaxis (falta operador) en la expresión de consulta '[ID]='C1' Y [ALM_ING]='NNPU"'. Por lo que, veo no me está reconociendo la fila de productos, dígase: reemplazó "IDP" por 'C1'; el cual es un producto del campo IDP

Comment: No, es un error de sintaxis, no de datos. Prueba con el `AND`

Comment: Roger, sos un genio. Efectivamente había que reemplazar el "Y" por un "AND" ¡por favor decíme cómo puedo ayudarte! Algún tipo de puntuación o algo, soy nuevo en stack

Comment: Lo habitual es darle a la pregunta por resuelta, dándole al check verde. Voy a revisarla y a cambiar el AND

Comment: ¡Excelente! Veo que ya está el AND así que le daré a resuelta. Espero algún ser tan grande como tú.